# How to verify user's email with remote tools without clicking the link in the email Firebase sent?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, email-validation

We are developing an app which requires users to verify their email adresses. When user signs up, Firebase sends email and if user verifies his email, he completes registration. This process works flawlessly.

I am not developer but have some basic skills about programing and I want to test app with some fake users so we need to create new users. User creation can be done with Firebase Console but we cannot pass email verification process since we do NOT have access to that fake emails to click verification links.

Is there a step by step tutorial of how to connect our Firebase database remotely and verify a fake user's email so user's email status is changed to verified? I guess there is a command line tool which lets developer to connect database remotly with access data and make some changes on user's status.

Comment: The database and verification are completely separate.

Comment: Just create a fake email account and test it with that!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Admin SDK for Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) to mark the user's email address as verified. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user):

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  emailVerified: true,
})
```

This is Node.js code, so you'll need to create a node script that contains this snippet. There are also examples for Java and Python on the page I linked.

Comment: I have raed all that documents. I understand the purpose of this platform but that should not mean I could not get help from here if i am not expert. You always give answers even when i ask from Youtube but your answers mostly does not help. You just give me the links i have already read. I know I need to setup this https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup and then https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users to verify email. But the question is how? Where / How will i run these codes with my project id and uid. Where / How can I copy paste the codes with my account credentals?

Comment: You're asking how to accomplish a complex technical task on a programming site. My answer is the minimal code I could figure out to accomplish that task. I'm sorry if that is not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same dificulty in order to validate the user by email, but here is the answer.

```
new_user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email,password)

auth.send_email_verification(new_user['idToken'])
```

This will send a link to user's email. The email will be the one in your firebase template

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but you can use fake emails and access the inbox of each, these emails are temporary for testing. You can use https://app.mailslurp.com/